Chart (circle) background off not working
EDIT: Add Screenshot

I am trying to use a Deneb Unit Chart (circle) from https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase in my Power BI Dashboard. Unfortunatelty I am not able to switch off the background of the visual. I have already tried several things. Set the background to "null" within the vegas settings, switch off the background in the Visualization properties. The background still remains with the "white" background. I am using Power BI Version: 2.138.1004.0 64-bit (November 2024) and the latest Deneb version. Thanks a lot for your help.
Code example:
{ "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
"width": 345,
"height": 345,
"padding": 15,
"background": "", --> I also tried with "null"
"signals": [ { "name": "textGradient", "update": "{gradient: 'linear', stops: [{offset: 0, color: '#036d19'}, {offset: 1, color: '#1db954'}]}" }, ...

Try:

Switch off the background in the Power BI Visualization properties.
Change the transparency there as well
Removed the background coding within the Deneb visual completely
Set the background setting within the Deneb visual to "null" or ""

Expecting:
I expect that the background of the Deneb visual is transparent and I see the background from the Canvas.

Try:   "background": "transparent",
EDIT:


Thanks a lot for your quick response. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Normally you can disable the background of the visual in the "General" settings under "Effects" but there only the border becomes "updated". The rest of the visual remains unchanged.
In former versions of Power BI in combo with Deneb it was working with disable the background.

It works just fine. I have tested it. You must be doing something else but without a .pbix, it is impossible to say.

I have tried to setup a completely new pbix but receive the same disbehavior. is it possible to share an example pbix with you? thanks a lot

Upload to an external site and share a link here

thanks a lot. please find the relevant link here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fxnScX9hlj1OybmVcd52cVjvzxtxIXEX?usp=sharing

I'm confused as it is working perfectly without me doing anything. I'll upload a screenshot.

me too. on my side it looks according to the screenshot attached. very strange

I use DENEB 1.7.2.1. and Power BI Version: 2.138.1004.0 64-bit (November 2024) Maybe this is an issue

Could it be related to dark mode? Try turning off dark mode and see if it changes things

this solved the issue. such a pain :). thanks a lot.
